# myContractInstance.balanceOf(gnoAccount) is not working in node js web3

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract through NodeJS using web3, but the `myContractInstance.balanceOf(gnoAccount)` function is not working 
 Here is my code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
// Connect to a geth server over JSON-RPC

var web3 = new Web3();


web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(console.log);


web3.eth.getBlock(
    "pending",
function (error, block) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(block.transactions.length); 
    }
})

web3.eth.getCoinbase(
    function(error, result){ 
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(result); 
    }
 })
var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burnFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_extraData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"approveAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"decimalUnits","type":"uint8"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"}];

//console.log(abi);

var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
var gnoAccount = "0x4*****************************************45"; // coinsbase address
var amount = 0.1; /* tokens you want to send */
var destination = "0x5*****************************************f6"; //destination address
var actbal = myContractInstance.balanceOf(gnoAccount);
console.log(actbal);
```

Please help anyone to solve this error.

Comment: Welcome to E SE. Consider adding the actual error message next time to get answers.

Comment: Where are you getting `contractAddress` from?

Comment: Contract address already created in ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity.The token transfer is working fine in Geth compiler but did not work in node js.

Comment: Try `myContractInstance.balanceOf.call(gnoAccount);`